# If $O$ is a point in square $ABCD$, then $\angle OAB+\angle OBC+\angle OCD+\angle ODA\ge\frac{3\pi}4$

Tags: geometry, inequality

> $O$ is a point in square $ABCD$. Show that
> $$\angle OAB+\angle OBC+\angle OCD+\angle ODA\ge\frac{3\pi}4$$

My solution is complex numbers. Let $-C=A=1$, $-D=B=i$. So
\begin{align*}&\mathrm{Arg}\left(\frac{B-A}{O-A}\cdot\frac{C-B}{O-B}\cdot\frac{D-C}{O-C}\cdot\frac{A-D}{O-D}\right)
\\={}&\mathrm{Arg}\left(\frac4{O^4-1}\right)=-\mathrm{Arg}(O^4-1).
\end{align*}
Here, $O$ is taken in the square, but $O^4$ is hard to manage. Firstly, when $|O|\le\dfrac{\sqrt2}2$, it can be in any direction then $O^4$’s locus is circle centered at $0$ with radius $\dfrac14$. However if $|O|$ is bigger, only some direction is in the square, namely $O$ moves on four arcs.

So my solution gets stuck here. You could actually change a method completely, but I’d like to see if my method would work.

Comment: Measure of angles is a bit of a delicate thing. Are you talking about oriented or non oriented angles? If they are oriented, I assume you take their measure between 0 and $2\pi$?

Comment: @Keen Normal angles, measured within $[0,\pi)$.

Comment: I'm not sure you can add the angles like that. You would need $\left|\mathrm{Arg}\left(\frac{B-A}{O-A}\right)\right|+\left|\mathrm{Arg}\left(\frac{C-B}{O-B}\right)\right|+\left|\mathrm{Arg}\left(\frac{D-C}{O-C}\right)\right|+\left|\mathrm{Arg}\left(\frac{A-D}{O-D}\right)\right|$. The absolute values (and the fact that the principal value of $\mathrm{arg}$ isn't an additive function) would make it different from what you have.

Comment: Actually on second thought, this might work out after all, but you'd need to be careful about specifying what exactly you're trying to find.

Comment: @Varun Vejalla If you think to oriented angles, taking the sum without absolute values is the right think to do. And it works (see my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be the square $A=1,\ B=i, \ C=-1, \ D=-i$ and :

$$f(z):=z^4-1 \ \ \text{and} \ \ g(z):=z^4$$

Have a look at the following picture :

[image]

Fig. 1: The interior of the green "drop" is the image by $g$ of (filled) square $S$. It can also be seen as the image by $g$ of square $OFAE$ or triangle $OAB$, with the  advantage that transformation $g$, restricted either to $OFAE$ of to $OAB$ is bijective. Animated version [here](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/wmckbbkt).

Your analysis has reduced the issue to the analysis of the opposite of the argument of $f(z)=z^4-1$ (I have replaced $O$ by $Z$ in order to enhance its variable status). As explained in the legend of fig. 1, the image of square $S$  by transformation $g$ is the interior of the drop-like curve  (in green) which, in a second step, is translated by $-1$ (interior of the red "drop").

**Remark:** The parametric equations of line $AB$ being :

$$x(t)=\frac{\cos(t)}{\cos(t)+\sin(t)}, y(t)=\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)+\sin(t)},\tag{1}$$

the parametric equations of the green drop are :

$$x(t)=\frac{\cos(4t)}{(\cos(t)+\sin(t))^4}, y(t)=\frac{\sin(4t)}{(\cos(t)+\sin(t))^4}$$

Explanation : taking a complex number at the power $n$ amounts to take the power $n$ of its modulus and multiply its argument by $n$.

One can obtain the green boundary by only taking the image by $g$ of line segment $AE$ for the upper part of the "drop" and line segment $AF$ for its lower part ; in fact the (interior of the) drop is the image by $g$ of the square $AEOF$ **or** of triangle $OAB$ (indeed, other squares or triangles can be obtained through a multiplication by some $i^k$, this multiplier vanishing with power $4$). Please note that the image by function $g$ of line segment $OE$ is line segment $OG$ with $G(-\frac14,0)$.

Now we can conclude. Lines $OG$ and $OH$, tangent to the red drop, permits to conclude that:

$$\frac{3\pi}{4} \le \arg(z^4-1) \le \frac{5\pi}{4} $$

as desired.

The proof that this interior angle symmetrical with respect to $x$-axis is $\pi/2$ comes plainly from the fact that it is the image of the $\pi/2$ angle $\angle DAC$ by analytic (therefore **conformal** = angle preserving) transformation $g$.

**Remarks :**

1. Moving point $Z$ (in the animated version) inside triangle $OAB$, the sum of angles remains in the vicinity of $180°$ ; unless point $M$ is very close to $A$, it's impossible to approach limit angles $3 \pi/4 = 135° $ and $5 \pi/4 = 225°$.
2. The denominator in (1) could be written $\sqrt{2}\cos(t-\frac{\pi}{4})$.

Comment: A remark: this kind of pear-shaped of drop-like forms is often encountered, for example with [Joukowski transformation](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheJoukowskiMappingAirfoilsFromCircles/) giving airfoils

Comment: We need to calculate to show the inequality but since you've figured out the polar function, I'll try myself.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think what follows is an elegant solution.

But it uses only very basic geometry.

[image]

Divide the square into $8$ equal parts  as shown. By symmetry, it suffices to prove that the sum of the four angles is at least $135^0$ if $O$ lies within the square $ IECH$ as shown.

There are several subcases:

$(1)$ $O$ lies on the diagonal $IC$:

[image]

$\Delta ODA \cong \Delta OBA \implies \alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta = 180^o \geq 135^o$
$$$$
$(2)$ $O$ lies on $EI$:

[image]

$OD=OC$ and $OA=OB \implies \alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta = 180^o \geq 135^o$
$$$$
$(3)$ $O$ lies on $EC$:

[image]

$\delta = 90^o$ and $\alpha \geq 45^o \implies \alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta \geq 135^o$

$$$$
$(4)$ $O$ lies inside $\Delta ECI$ but not on the boundary:

[image]

$\tan \gamma \gt \tan x \implies \gamma \gt x \implies \gamma + \delta \gt 90^0$

Since $\alpha \gt 45^o$, $ \alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta \geq 135^o$
$$$$
$(5)$ $O$ lies inside $\Delta IHC$:

[image]

$\tan \delta \gt \tan y \implies \delta \gt y \implies \alpha + \delta \gt 90^0$

Since $\gamma \gt 45^o$, $ \alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta \geq 135^o$
$$$$
The remaining $2$ cases where $O$ lies on $CH$ or $IH$ can be dealt with similarly.

Comment: [+1] Well done, and simple.

Comment: your last two cases are symmetric. In fact, only considering $\triangle IEC$ - its three sides and interior is sufficient.

Comment: @dezdichado Thank you for pointing out the symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

If someone wants to have an entirely algebraic trigonometric solution, not using complex numbers, nor having any geometric insight, below is one:

Let's assume $A=(0,0), B=(0,1), C=(1,1), D=(1,0)$, and $O=(a,b)$, where $0<a,b<1$.
It is easy to see that:
$$\angle OAB=\arctan \frac{a}{b}\\ \angle OBC=\arctan \frac{1-b}{a}\\\angle OCD=\arctan \frac{1-a}{1-b}\\\angle ODA=\arctan \frac{b}{1-a}.\\$$

Now, if $a=b$, or $a+b=1$, with the help of the relation $\arctan x+ \arctan \frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we get that:
$$A=\arctan \frac{a}{b}+\arctan \frac{1-b}{a}+\arctan \frac{1-a}{1-b}+\arctan \frac{b}{1-a}=\pi.$$

Hence four cases happen:

$$1>b+a, b>a \\ 1>b+a, a>b\\a+b>1, a>b\\a+b>1, b>a .$$

Assume $1>b+a, b>a$, or $a+b>1, a>b.$ In these cases, $\frac{1-b}{a}>\frac{1-a}{b}$ So,

$$A=\arctan \frac{a}{b}+\arctan \frac{1-b}{a}+\arctan \frac{1-a}{1-b}+\arctan \frac{b}{1-a}>\\\arctan \frac{a}{b}+(\arctan \frac{1-a}{b}+\arctan \frac{b}{1-a})+\arctan \frac{1-a}{1-b}=\\ \frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan \frac{a}{b}+\arctan \frac{1-a}{1-b}.$$
On the other hand, since either $a>b$ or $b>a$, $\arctan \frac{a}{b}+\arctan \frac{1-a}{1-b}> \frac{\pi}{4}$ (note that $\arctan 1= \frac{\pi}{4}$). As a result, $A>\frac{3\pi}{4}.$

If we assume $1>a+b, a>b$ or $a+b>1, b>a$, in these cases, $\frac {a}{b}>\frac{1-b}{1-a}$. So,
$$A=\arctan \frac{a}{b}+\arctan \frac{1-b}{a}+\arctan \frac{1-a}{1-b}+\arctan \frac{b}{1-a}>\\ (\arctan \frac{1-b}{1-a}+\arctan \frac{1-a}{1-b})+\arctan \frac{1-b}{a}+\arctan \frac{b}{1-a}=\\ \frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan \frac{1-b}{a}+\arctan \frac{b}{1-a};$$

since either $a+b>1$ or $1>a+b$, we have $\arctan \frac{1-b}{a}+\arctan \frac{b}{1-a}> \frac{\pi}{4}$. So, $A>\frac{3\pi}{4}.$

We are done.

[image]

Fig. 1 : Representation of the sum of the four angles as a surface $z=f(a,b)$ (for $0<a,b<1$). One notices a natural invariance by $k \pi/2$ rotations around point $(1/2,1/2)$.

Comment: 1) You could have assumed WLOG that $0\le a,b\le 1/2$ due to the symmetry with respect to center $(1/2,1/2)$ 2) All the best for you in these hard times...

Comment: Do you allow me to include in your answer a representation of your expression as a surface ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Hello. Yes Sir. Please feel free to edit/upgrade it.

Comment: An afterthought : it seems that you have switched the roles of abscissas and ordinates: $(a,b)$ should be $(b,a)$

Comment: I just added the graphical representation which is rather flat. Feel free in particular to modify the legend !

Comment: I don't think the order of $(a,b)$ is reversed just because, unlike the shapes in the other solution, the points $D$ and $B$, set at the beginning of the post , are somehow replaced with each other. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand.